# Scrapy TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy, python-venv

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import csv
import os
from selectorlib import Extractor
import re 

class AlibabaCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    custom_settings = {
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False
    }
    start_urls = ['http://alibaba.com/']
    extractor = Extractor.from_yaml_file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/search_results.yml"))
    max_pages = 5

    def start_requests(self):
        """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                search_text=keyword["keyword"]
                url="https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText={0}&viewtype=G".format(
                    search_text)
                # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text})


    def parse(self, response):
        data = self.extractor.extract(response.text,base_url=response.url)
        for product in data['products']:
            yield product
        
        # Try paginating if there is data
        if data['products']:
            if '&page=' not in response.url and self.max_pages>=2:
                yield Request(response.request.url+"&page=2")
            else:
                url = response.request.url
                current_page_no = re.findall('page=(\d+)',url)[0]
                next_page_no = int(current_page_no)+1
                url = re.sub('(^.*?&page\=)(\d+)(.*$)',rf"\g<1>{next_page_no}\g<3>",url)
                if next_page_no <= self.max_pages:
                    yield Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```

it looks like there is a problem between my main file and my product file but i can't seem to be able to find the problem

```
products:
    css: 'div[data-content="productItem"]'
    multiple: true
    type: Text
    children:
        name:
            css: a.organic-gallery-title
            type: Text
        price:
            css: 'p.gallery-offer-price span'
            type: Text
        seller_name:
            css: a.organic-gallery-offer__seller-company
            type: Text
        seller_years:
            css: span.seller-tag__year
            type: Text
        seller_response_rate:
            css: span.seller-tag__response-rate
            type: Text
        image:
            css: 'a.organic-gallery-offer__img-section img'
            type: Attribute
            attribute: src
        link:
            css: a.organic-gallery-title
            type: Link
```

any ideas, i am really lost! i run everything in a python virtual environment

after running the code i was supposed to get a list of all the data i requested but i keep getting this error whatever i try to do

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 279, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 350, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 350, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 352, in <genexpr>
    return (self._set_referer(r, response) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 31, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, response, spider))
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapingenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MOATASSIM\Documents\developedbymoe\MyProjects\WebScraping\scrapy_alibaba\scrapy_alibaba\spiders\alibaba_crawler.py", line 35, in parse
    for product in data['products']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

here is my console

Comment: Please add full error traceback to your question.

Comment: i added the traceback for you to see

Comment: Check what `data` contains after the line `data = self.extractor.extract(response.text,base_url=response.url)`. It looks like it doesn't properly get the data you think it does.